# Adding Monetico payment to Magento

Tags: module, payment

I would like to add a Monetico electronic terminal payment to my Magento shop.

The Monetico service do not give any ready to install module for magento but only few php functions / examples.

As I need it to work as soon as possible, I would like to avoid developing a full module to implement it... Is there a generic module that can be used?

Have you already worked on a Monetico solution?

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to develop your own payment gateway module:**

You need to analyse et understand how the payment gateway are implemented in Magento2. Magento provides some sample code in order to help you: 
https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-payment-gateway

So get the monetico code to understand how the basic works. Retrieve the encrypt key, create the MAC, send the data and redirect the customer to Monetico, get the notification from Monetico and process the order. You can dowload Monetico sample code here: 
https://www.monetico-paiement.fr/fr/installer/telechargements/kit_telechargeable.aspx

Check out the official documentation for further details about how to integrate checkout payment solution:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_payment.html

**If you want to go with an existing solution:**

Magento 1, which is FREE and was developed in partnership with the Crédit-Mutuel bank:
[CyberMut(Monetico)-Magento Git](https://github.com/quadra-informatique/CyberMut-Magento). 
Magento 2, there is a paid extension, developed by a french company:
[Monetico CM-CIC Magento 2 module](http://store.bird.eu/magento-extensions/monetico-cm-cic.html)